# Group by column. If null, group by other column MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, case

I have this query:

```
SELECT 
 vcl.id,
     vcl.batch_id,
     vcl.type,
     vcl.amount,
     vcl.date
FROM vrcorporateledger vcl
LEFT JOIN payroll_list pl ON pl.id = vcl.batch_id
```

[image: query output]

which gives the following output:

Whenever there is "CREDIT" in col type I want to increase the running balance by the value in col amount; whenever there is "DEBIT" in col type I want to decrease the accumulated balance by the value in col amount after grouping by batch_id col. So expected result is:

1000-2+5-4-49=950.

If possible I want to also create a column "balance" where at each point/step I see the resulting balance.

expected output like:

[image: Expected output like this]

Comment: Same advice as before basically

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT type,
       SUM(amount) OVER (PARTITION BY CASE type WHEN 'CREDIT' THEN RAND()
                                                WHEN 'DEBIT' THEN batchID
                                                ELSE 0 END ) amount,
       MIN(`date`) OVER (PARTITION BY CASE type WHEN 'CREDIT' THEN RAND()
                                                WHEN 'DEBIT' THEN batchID
                                                ELSE 0 END ) `date`,
       SUM(CASE type WHEN 'CREDIT' THEN amount
                     WHEN 'DEBIT' THEN -amount
                     ELSE 0 END) OVER (ORDER BY `date`) balance,
       batchID,
       LEAD(batchID) OVER (ORDER BY `date`) next_batchID
FROM source_data
)
SELECT type, 
       amount, 
       balance, 
       `date`
FROM cte
WHERE CASE WHEN batchID = next_batchID THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=75255728f6d64a91a2ebf62edc2d0a0b

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for [SQL Window functions](https://mode.com/sql-tutorial/sql-window-functions/). They basically allow you to do an aggregate "over a partition".

On a side note: This is a really bad way of calculating doing running balance.

I would strongly suggest storing balance in a separate column at runtime. This should allow you to:

- have a strict check even when rows are changed or deleted
- normal speed when you have millions of records

Answer (score 0):

If your MySQL version is 8 or above then you can use common table expression with window function as below:

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
create table vrcorporateledger (id int,batch_id int,type varchar(10),amount float,Tdate timestamp);

insert into vrcorporateledger  values (1,null,'CREDIT',1000,'2021/03/04 06:19:00');
insert into vrcorporateledger  values (2,1,'DEBIT',1,'2021/03/04 07:00:19');
insert into vrcorporateledger  values (3,1,'DEBIT',1,'2021/03/04 07:00:25');
insert into vrcorporateledger  values (4,null,'CREDIT',5,'2021/03/05 06:19:00');
insert into vrcorporateledger  values (5,2,'DEBIT',1,'2021/03/04 08:58:10');
insert into vrcorporateledger  values (6,2,'DEBIT',3,'2021/03/04 08:58:16');
insert into vrcorporateledger  values (7,null,'DEBIT',49,'2021/03/04 16:42:33');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT id,type,
       (case when batch_id is null then (case when type='DEBIT' then -amount else amount end) else 
       SUM(case when type='DEBIT' then -amount else amount end) OVER (PARTITION BY batch_id)end) amount,
       (case when batch_id is null then Tdate else
       MIN(Tdate) OVER (PARTITION BY batch_id ) end) Trandate,       
       batch_id,
       LEAD(batch_id) OVER (ORDER BY id) next_batch
       
FROM vrcorporateledger
)
SELECT type, 
       amount, 
       sum(amount)over(order by id) running_balance,       
       Trandate date
FROM cte
WHERE  batch_id is null or batch_id =next_batch
order by id;
```

| type | amount | date | running_balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CREDIT | 1000 | 2021-03-04 06:19:00 | 1000 |
| DEBIT | -2 | 2021-03-04 07:00:19 | 998 |
| CREDIT | 5 | 2021-03-05 06:19:00 | 1003 |
| DEBIT | -4 | 2021-03-04 08:58:10 | 999 |
| DEBIT | -49 | 2021-03-04 16:42:33 | 950 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)